# how to replace image part via jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I need to replace a part of image same like this site `http://floorsync.esignserver1.com/` 
is there any jquery plugin available to do this and what Technic is used behind this type of work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.. everyone is giving you -1 as your question is not clear, and you have not shown any efforts. Please update your question to get proper answer.

Comment: @Bhupzoer Shubham is right. You should see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should show some of your research before asking a question. What you have tried or anything sort of it?

Answer (score 0):

They are replacing the whole image, not part of it. So they have 1 image per each combination.